# Unexpected dtype in .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to tidy up some data that I imported from a CSV file. I am trying to drop all rows with a negative value in the 'Active Power' column.

I am using Python 3.

- Imported the csv file using `pd.read_csv()`
- Specified dtype as float using `.astype('float')`

When then trying to drop the appropriate cells I get

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Here is the code:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data['Control'] = data['Control'].astype('float')
data['Power'] = data['Power'].astype('float')
print(data.dtypes)

nan_counter = data.isna().sum()
print(nan_counter)
```

```
Control  float64
Power    float64
dtype: object

Control      0
Power        0
dtype: int64
```

Problematic Part:

```
data = data.drop(data[data["Power" < 0.0]].index, inplace = True)
```

Error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I get the same error (str vs int, in that case) if I set the data type as int and use < 0 instead of < 0.0

---

Additional information regarding dataframe:

```
print(data) #data before attempting to filter negative power values

        Control   Power
249182         0.3         -8.82
132350         0.3         -7.08
56440         -0.2         -4.66
265662         2.8         -1.17
283739        -0.4          0.00
...            ...           ...
35526         98.5        906.23
35475         98.5        906.23
35338         98.6        906.25
35834         98.5        906.28
35793         98.5        906.39

[286996 rows x 2 columns]
```

```
print(cleanish_data) #dataframe after removing 'negative values'

        Control  Power
143497        -0.3           0.0
172367         0.1           0.0
172366         0.2           0.0
172365         0.2           0.0
172364         0.2           0.0
...            ...           ...
201443         0.2           0.0
201460         0.1           0.0
201445         0.2           0.0
201444         0.2           0.0
201446         0.2           0.0

[137023 rows x 2 columns]
```

Result of improved (added bracket) code, seems to drop everything but the `power = 0`. Intended was that rows are dropped where power is less than 0.

Comment: What do you not understand from the error message ?

Comment: You probably don't have a column named `"Power" < 0.0`

Comment: You put the closing bracket in the wrong place. `data["Power" < 0.0]` should be `data["Power"] < 0.0`. I'm voting to close the question because the problem was caused by a typo. In the future, please make a [mre] and ask a specific question about it; see [ask].

Comment: BTW, when comparing real numbers, the type/dtype doesn't matter. You can do `data["Power"] < 0` for simplicity.

Comment: @JonSG I'm not sure what you're talking about... `"Power" < 0.0` isn't a name, it's a `TypeError`. But they clearly have a column named `Power`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare the column name `"Power"` with the float value 0.0, which results in a TypeError (you can't use `<` to compare a string to a float). You need to compare the values in the "Power" column with 0.0 to filter the rows with negative values:

```py
data.drop(data[data['Power'] < 0.0].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Follow up question: If I implement your solution, and then `print(data)` I get the output `None`. 
I've manually checked and there should only be 5 rows deleted (that have a value of less than 0 for Power). Did I accidentally delete the entire data frame? Can you give advice from the data provided?

Comment: What happens if you try it like this (instead of using drop())? data = data[data['Power'] >= 0.0]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just found a solution. Read through the documentation and switching `inplace` to `False` gives me the result I was looking for.

Comment: Ran into a funny error though, with both the `inplace = False` and your suggested work around: It now drops all rows except where `power = 0`. Confuses me, because it is not even 'just the opposite'...
Any idea as to why?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data to your question? It should contain positive, negative and 0 values in the "power" column.

Comment: @felix_the_cat `.drop(..., inplace=True)` returns `None` because it's an in-place operation. Cf. [Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?](/q/11205254/4518341)

Comment: [Please avoid answering questions caused by a typo](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366141/4518341)